# Does anyone know a basepoint-free construction of universal covers?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fundamental-group, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be a real manifold (for simplicity). The standard construction of the universal cover $\varphi: \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ involves fixing a basepoint $p \in X$ and considering homotopy classes of paths from $p$ to $x \in X$.

Is there an alternative construction of $\varphi$ that avoids choosing a basepoint?

Comment: Must $X$ be connected?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I'm happy to assume connected, if it helps.

Comment: If $X$ is *path* connected, and $\tilde X_p$ is the universal cover constructed from the chosen point $p$, then it seems like you could probably give a description of $\bigsqcup_p \tilde X_p$ that doesn't involve choosing $p$ (all paths in $X$, up to endpoints-fixed homotopy, maybe?), and then impose an equivalence relation that puts $\xi_p \in \tilde X_p$ equivalent to $\xi_q \in \tilde X_q$ if there is some path $\xi_{pq}$ from $p$ to $q$ such that $\xi_p$ is the concatenation of $\xi_{pq}$ and $\xi_q$.

Comment: Just like there is no *the* algebraic closure of a field, I think there should not be a *the* universal cover of a space. Any two constructions are isomorphic, but the set of isomorphisms (over $X$) is a torsor under $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: Even if there was such a basepoint-free construction, I doubt that one could verify for two given spaces $X$ and $Y$ that $X$ is the universal cover of $Y$ without choosing a basepoint in $Y$. Already for $X=\mathbb R$ (considered merely as an affine line with the canonical basepoint $0$ ``forgotten'') and $Y=S^1$ this seems difficult to me.

Comment: @BK What do you mean? Doesn't a universal cover come with the data of a map $X \longrightarrow Y$?

Comment: @ Kim: Of course you're right. I should have more precisely said that I doubt one can write down a covering map $\mathbb R \to S^1$ without choosing a basepoint. I hereby challenge anyone reading this comment to do so ;-)

Comment: Addition to my previous comment: Here I had the definition  $S^1:=\{x\in \mathbb C: |x|=1\}$ in mind. If we define $S^1:=\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ then of course the covering map is canonical and needs no basepoint as $\mathbb Z$ acts on $\mathbb R$ even if we consider the latter merely as an affine line.

Comment: @BK If you take that as your definition of $S^1$, doesn't it come with a canonical basepoint (i.e. the identity element 1 in the group)?

Comment: It does, but we can ignore this just as we can forget that $\mathbb R$ has a canonical basepoint. Then $S^1$ is just a circle in the "plane without a coordinate system".

Comment: If you stipulate that the construction should be functorial with respect to diffeomorphisms and that the map $\tilde X\to X$ should be natural, then it's impossible even for $S^1$.

Comment: I realised that I'm a little unhappy with my earlier comment, because the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ itself relies on a choice, so is only well-defined up to inner automorphism. I believe that this choice and the choice of the universal cover, although related, should not cancel out (as should become visible in the abelian case). Maybe someone who speaks $\infty$-groupoids should write a coherent answer [pun intended].

Comment: @TomGoodwillie How do we prove this?

Comment: @Kim: perform the natural map associated to  the universal cover for every translation of the circle.

Comment: @RyanBudney So it amounts to a failure to embed $S^1$ into $\mathbf{R}$?

Comment: Sure there is: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reconstruction+of+covering+spaces+from+monodromy#InTermsOfACoend

Comment: To justify my assertion: The group of diffeomorphisms $S^1\to S^1$ has no compatible action on $\mathbb R$ (i.e. none satisfying the naturality that I require, i.e. no action such that the projection $\mathbb R\to S^1$ intertwines it with the action on $S^1$). Even the subgroup generated by a rotation $R:S^1\to S^1$ of order $2$ has no such action.

Comment: @David Roberts: It is explained at nlab that covering spaces are equivalent to functors from the fundamental groupoid to Set. But this means that making a universal covering space (of connected $X$) without using a basepoint corresponds to   taking any connected groupoid and canonically making a functor to Set such that for each object in the groupoid the associated action of the corresponding group is free and transitive. If you could do that in a way that was functorial, even with respect to equivalences of groupoids, then I believe you would have a contradiction.

Comment: Probably this is implicit in some of the things already written, but  perhaps it's worth saying explicitly.  The answer depends on what you think a universal cover is. If it's a cover that covers all covers, then you can just note that the fibre product of a family of covers is a common cover, and then apply Zorn's lemma.  But it's not clear that the resulting space is simply connected, and I suspect you need base points for that.

Comment: @HJRW A correction and a comment on HJRW's answer: A fiber product of connected covers need not be connected, so you need to take a connected component of the fiber product. Also, I at first was skeptical that Zorn was needed, but then I realized I wasn't sure how to prove the product over all covers was nonempty without Zorn, so maybe you do?

Comment: Here is a version which I think does not use Zorn. Let $X$ be a nonempty topological space. Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of all topologies on $X \times \mathbb{Z}$ for which the projection map $\pi: X \times \mathbb{Z} \to X$ is a cover. Since a topology is a subset of the power set of $X$, the collection $\mathcal{I}$ really is a set. For $i \in I$, I'll write $Y_i$ for the corresponding topological space and $\pi_i : Y_i \to X$ for the covering map. Let $F = \{ (y_i) \in \prod_{i \in \mathcal{I}} Y_i : \pi_i(y_i) = \pi_j(y_j) \forall i,j \in \mathcal{I} \}$. (continued)

Comment: Now I do need to single out a point $x \in X$ for a moment: We know that $F$ is nonempty because it contains the point which is $(x,0)$ in every $Y_i$. But now we can throw that point away again and choose a connected component of $F$ (fortunately, since $X$ is connected, I only need to choose once). It shouldn't be too hard to show that this is a cover and every cover factors through it; of course, without a basepoint, there is no uniqueness to the factorization.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer — yes, I forgot to mention that you should pass to a connected component. I don’t know if Zorn is needed — your Zornless argument seems OK to me.

Comment: @Tom I believe you, but the OP asked for a construction of the universal covering space without choice of basepoint, and the page I linked does that. It doesn't claim that the projection map is natural or anything stronger than merely constructing $\widetilde{X}$.

Comment: @David Roberts I think that that nlab discussion has an error (in the part that begins by saying that the dependence on the basepoint is spurious). That equalizer is taking the covering spaces $B_b$ associated to all possible basepoints $b\in B$ and gluing them together using all possible paths between one basepoint and another. This is equivalent (in the connected case) to taking a universal cover and dividing by the group of deck transformations.

Comment: @Tom ah, that seems likely, now you mention it. I'll raise this at the nForum. I think I recall who wrote that (a few years back now!)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that homotopy-theorists often fall into the habit of working mainly with based spaces, even when they don't need to. It can be instructive to notice when the use of a basepoint is unnecessary, even artificial. But it's also important to notice the parts of the subject where the use of a basepoint is necessary. This (the topic of universal covering spaces) is one of those parts.

By "universal covering space" of a connected manifold $M$ I assume we mean a simply connected manifold $\tilde M$ with covering map $p:\tilde M\to M$. (By "simply connected" I mean connected and having trivial $\pi_1$ for one, hence any, basepoint. The empty space is not connected.)

There is always a universal covering space, and to explain how to make one we usually start by picking a point $x\in M$. Any two universal covering spaces, no matter how they are constructed, are related by an isomorphism, by which I mean a diffeomorphism that respects the projection to $M$. But this isomorphism is not unique, because for any such $(\tilde M,p)$ there is a group of isomorphisms $\tilde M\to \tilde M$ (i.e. deck transformations), a nontrivial group except in the case when $M$ itself is simply connected.

Suppose that there were a way of making a universal covering space $\tilde M$ that did not depend on a choice of basepoint (or any other arbitrary choice), and suppose that for $x\in M$ there was a canonical isomorphism between this $\tilde M$ and the one determined by $x$.

But this would imply that when we use two points $x\in M$ to make  two universal covering spaces of $M$ then there is a canonical isomorphism between these.

Every homotopy class of paths from $x$ to $y$ in $M$ (homotopy with endpoints fixed) determines an isomorphism between the two covering spaces, and every isomorphism arises from exactly one such homotopy class. So if we had a canonical isomorphism we would have a canonical homotopy class of paths from $x$ to $y$. And surely we don't.

(That's not rigorous, because what does "canonical" mean? But surely if one had an actual recipe for making an $\tilde M$ for $M$ without first making some arbitrary choice then for any diffeomorphism $h:M_1\cong M_2$ the choice of canonical path classes in $M_1$ would be related by $h$ to the corresponding choice in $M_2$. In particular this would be the case for a reflection $S^1\to S^1$ that fixes two points $x$ and $y$ but of course does not fix any class of paths from $x$ to $y$.)

Answer (score 10):

Part  of 10.5.8 of [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) is, in a more usual notation, essentially  the following, in which $\sigma, \tau$ are the source and target maps, $St_G x$ is $\sigma ^{-1} x$,    by $N$ is *totally disconnected* is meant that $N(x,y)$ is empty for $x \ne y$, and *normality* of $N$ in $G$ also means that $N,G$ have the same set of objects:

Let $X$  be a  space which admits a universal cover, and let $N$ be a totally disconnected normal subgroupoid of the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1( X) $,  Then the set of elements of the
quotient groupoid $\pi_1(X)/N$ may be given a topology such that the projection
$$q = (\sigma, \tau) : \pi_1(X)/N \to  X \times X$$ is a covering map and for $x \in  X$  the target map $\tau :St_{\pi_1(  X)/N} \to X$ is the covering map determined by the normal subgroup $N(x)$ of $\pi_1(X, x)$.

So this uses all the points of $X$ and puts all these covers into a covering space, which means you don't make a choice of base point;  instead you use all the choices. Further, $\pi_1(X)/N$ with this topology is actually a topological groupoid.

This may be the optimal  way of answering the question.

I believe that you can do a similar trick with getting a bundle of $n$-th homotopy groups over $X$ if $X$ admits a universal cover, and that this was to be in the Dyer and Eilenberg book on algebraic topology.

Comment: I don't understand. It appears that the points mapping to $x\in X$ can be made to correspond in a definite way with the elements of $\pi_1(X,x)$. But what is this canonical action of the group $\pi_1(X,x)$ on the set $\pi_1(X,x)$? I suspect that it is conjugation, rather than being free and transitive.

Comment: Any group $G$ acts on its  underlying set $U(G)$ by left multiplication. Won;t that do? In a groupoid $G$, and $x \in Ob(G)$ the group $G(x)$ acts on the set $St_G (x)$. in the same way.(One needs to be careful on conventions for writing multiplication!)

Comment: What is your functor from $G$ to Set such that for every object x this functor restricted to $G(x)$ gives you a group acting on itself by left multiplication?

Comment: How can a morphism $x\to y$ in $G$ possibly give you an isomorphism of sets $U(G(x))\to U(G(y))$ in a canonical way, except by conjugation?

Comment: @Tom Hi! Maybe introducing $U$  for groups is misleading.for the groupoid case.In this latter case , if  $g: x \to y$ and $a: x \to x$ then $ga: x to y$, and that gives the action of the group $G(x)$ on the set $St_G (x)$ (according to the conventions of T&G),   Of course $G(x)$ is bijective with $(G(x,y)$ but not with $St_Gx$.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood you. But you are not asserting that there is a way of constructing a universal (connected) covering space of a connected space $X$ without choosing a base point. You are basically saying that if you make such a covering space once for every base point in $X$ and form their disjoint union then you can topologize that in such a way that it is a covering space of $X\times X$.

Comment: Exactly! One hopes that such specific description will be of use.

Comment: I add that there was no connectivity assumption (except locally). The intention of that Chapter was also to advertise the notion of covering morphisms of groupoids as _algebraic models_ of covering morphisms of spaces.

Answer (score 9):

[UPDATE: As Tom Goodwillie points out, this is much more complicated than necessary and misunderstands the line of argument that he had in mind.  Still, it has some interesting features so I will leave it here.]

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the category of connected smooth manifolds and smooth maps, let $\mathcal{M}_1$ be the subcategory with the same objects whose morphisms are the diffeomorphisms, and let $J\colon\mathcal{M}_1\to\mathcal{M}$ be the inclusion.  Suppose we have a functor $U\colon\mathcal{M}_1\to\mathcal{M}$ and a natural map $p\colon UM\to JM$ that is a universal cover for all $M$.  Consider $S^1$ as the usual subspace of $\mathbb{C}$, and choose a point $a\in p^{-1}\{1\}\subset U(S^1)$.  For $z\in S^1$ we can define $\mu_z\in\mathcal{M}_1(S^1,S^1)$ by $\mu_z(u)=zu$, and then define $s(z)=U(\mu_z)(a)\in U(S^1)$.  This defines a section $s$ of the map $p\colon U(S^1)\to S^1$.  If we make enough additional assumptions to ensure that $s$ is continuous, then we arrive at a contradiction.

I think that in fact no additional assumptions are needed, but that needs a slightly different approach.  We can identify $S^1$ with $\mathbb{R}P^1$, and then we have an action of the group $G=PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$.  Let $H$ be the upper triangular subgroup, which is the stabiliser of the basepoint $1\in S^1$.  For $h\in H$ there is a unique $h'\colon U(S^1)\to U(S^1)$ with $ph'=hp$ and $h'(a)=a$.  The map $Fh$ need not obviously fix $a$ so it need not coincide with $h'$, but it must have $Fh=\phi(h)\circ h'$ for some deck transformation $\phi(h)$.  The group of deck transformations can be identified with $\pi_1(S^1,1)=\mathbb{Z}$, and $H$ acts on this in a natural way (independent of the supposed existence of $U$).  Using the connectivity of $H$ we see that this action is trivial.   I think it follows that $\phi\colon H\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism, but any element $h\in H$ has $n$'th roots for all $n>0$, and this forces $\phi$ to be trivial, so $Fh=h'$ for all $h$.  This proves that $Fh$ depends continuously on $h$ for $h\in H$.  Moreover, one can find $h_z,k_z\in H$ such that the entries are rational functions of $z$ and $\mu_z=h_z\mu_{-1}k_z$.  It follows that $F(\mu_z)$ depends continuously on $z$ except possibly at finitely many values of $z$.  These possible exceptions can then be removed by an auxiliary argument with the group structure.

Comment: I had something simpler in mind. See my later comment.

Answer (score 6):

If you want something functorial and base-point-independent, one option is the following $\widetilde X$ bundle over $X$.  It combines all the base-point-dependent covering spaces into one gadget.

Let $C(X)$ be the space of all maps $I \to X$, modulo homotopy-rel-end-points.  Let $p:C(X) \to X$ be the evaluation at the initial endpoint of $I$.  It's easy to see that $p^{-1}(x)$ is the usual universal cover $\widetilde X_x$ contructed using the base point $x\in X$.  So $p : C(X) \to X$ is an $\widetilde X$ bundle over $X$.

The assignment
$$
  X \; \mapsto \; (p : C(X) \to X)
$$
is functorial in $X$.

Comment: Here $p: C(X)  \to X$ is what I have called $\sigma:  \pi_1(X) \to X$.

Comment: Thanks.  I had not noticed that you were describing essentially the same thing.

Comment: I think it is also useful to investigate the target category - covering morphisms of groupoids.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another attempt at pinning down the meaning of "canonical" in reference to  Tom's answer.

1. Let $X$ be a nice space (connected, locally path-connected and semi-locally simply connected).
2. Let $\pi_X$ be the fundamental groupoid of $X$: this is a category whose objects
   are points $x\in X$, where a morphism $x\to y$ is a homotopy class of path fixing the endpoints.
3. Let $U_X$ be the groupoid of universal covers: an object is a universal cover $X_1 \to X$ and a morphism $X_1 \to X_2$ is an isomorphism of covers over the identity map of $X$.

There is a functor $$f:\pi_X\to U_X$$ (i.e., a homomorphism of groupoids)  given by the usual construction of a universal cover. Then $f$ is an equivalence of categories (covering space theory).

Let $$g: U_X \to \pi_X$$ be its adjoint (which is defined up to unique isomorphism).

This means for any $\tilde X\in U_X$, with $g(\tilde X) = x\in X$ we have a preferred
isomorphism 
$$
f(x) \cong \tilde X\, .
$$

In other words, a universal cover determines a basepoint and a basepoint determines a universal cover.

Comment: The correspondence {universal covers} $\leftrightarrow$ {basepoints} depends on the choice of $g$, right? I agree $g$ is unique up to unique isomorphism, but it is not literally unique on the nose, and since there is only one isomorphism class in $\pi_X$, knowing $g(\tilde{X})$ only up to isomorphism is no information. I believe it is possible to choose $g$ to be constant on the level of objects.

Comment: That is of course correct (both assertions).